# Binary isn't persisted in dockerfile

Tags: docker

Newbie to Docker and what appears to be a simple issue isn't working. I would like to build a binary inside of a dockerfile and execute the binary in `docker-compose`.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.10

ENV DIR=/go/src/api

RUN go get github.com/Masterminds/glide

WORKDIR $DIR

ADD glide.yaml glide.yaml
ADD glide.lock glide.lock
RUN glide install

COPY . $DIR

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o main .

CMD main
```

And in my `docker-compose.yml` I have this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

However, there's no `main` executable when run from docker-compose.  I've actually added a `command: ls` to the docker-compose file and it's not there.  I've then added a `ls` to the Dockerfile image and `main` is there.

How do I prevent `main` from being lost in translation?

Comment: Is that your entire docker-compose.yml? Checking that you didn't define a volume.

Comment: What do you mean, lost in translation? I never see you do anything with main? Where do you copy/add/mount it?

Comment: Do I need to have a volume for it?  The binary is made as part of the image.  It cannot find the file because on `docker-compose up` it throws an error that `main` is not found.